# Vue 3's Provide / Inject using the Options API

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I've been trying to follow the documentation for the API on the Vue 3 website which says to use `app.provide('keyName',variable)` inside your `main.js` file like so:

```
import App from './App.vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

const app = createApp(App)

app.provide('axios', axios)

app.use('Vue')
app.mount('#app')
```

Then inject and use it in your child component like so:

```
export default {
  inject: ['axios'],
  ...
  createUser (data) {
    return this.axios.post('/users', data)
  }
}
```

However doing so just gives me this error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'post')
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I didn't see any about an import unless you're using the Composition API. Can provide / inject be called from within a .js file? I would expect so as long as its within a `export default {}` statement

Ive tried following the [API](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html#app-level-provide) to a "T" but it simply refuses to work for me. Also tried searching the web for solutions but everything I've found says what I'm doing should be working just fine.

Comment: if you try provide/injecting basic strings, like in the docs, does that at least work?  also, potentially unrelated but what is `app.use('Vue')` in `main.js` doing exactly? as far as I know that should be throwing an error

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out - it wasnt throwing an error in my app, just a warning. I dont know how I missed that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, see the playground.

But is not absolutely necessary, since with the browser library version axios is globally defined and could be accessed also without `inject`

You could also save yourself some time with the [`vue-axios`](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios) plugin.

### Example

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const myComponent = {
  inject: ['axios'],
  created() {    
    this.axios.get('/')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
     .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  },
  template: '<div>My Component</div>'
}

const App = {
  components: { 
    myComponent
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.provide('axios', axios)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">  
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.3.1/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think I found my issue, for whatever reason every time I try to use 'this' both in and out of an arrow function, it returns either 'undefined' or if its a export statement it'll represent the export statement. So I guess that leads me to "how do I get 'this' to point to the vue instance?"

Comment: where are you trying to use an arrow function?  it's a feature of JavaScript that arrow functions create their own enclosed context and don't have their own `this`.  If you can, just use normal function and the Vue instance will be accessible